# Python, read specific Block of files

Tags: python

i have this Text  and i want to read specific blocks of it:

```
fist one:
=======
1
b
2
c
3

next one:
=========
4
5
d
6

7


third one:
=======
8
9
e
10


fourth one:
=======
11
12
d
13
```

i want to read JUST the numbers of each block and write them in one file.
output should be:

```
1
b
2
c
3
8
9
e
10
```

i'm sorry because i cant write my code here because the context is different.
i tried with for loops, regex and readline(s) and Startwith ("fist one:") but cannot skip the '=====' i want to check the name of the Block if its match and then take just the numbers.

```
many thanks for your help
```

Comment: why are 4,5,6,7 and 11,12,13 not written?

Comment: @PatrickArtner thanks for your replay. i want to Exclude them.

Comment: How do you specify _which_ block to use or skip?

Comment: @PatrickArtner  By the name of the Block :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read all lines, and process them - if a line is in a list of known block names, set some booleans.Skip the next ==== line and capture all lines following this one until either:

- a new block name that should be read is given ( then you need to "eat" an ==== again)
- a ===== line comes ( == end of capturing because we already passsed the next blocks title and do not want to keep its numbers)
- file is at its end

This could look like so:

```
# write data
with open("f.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("""fist one:\n=======\n1\n2\n3\n\nnext one:\n=========\n4\n5\n6\n\n7\n\n
third one:\n=======\n8\n9\n10\n\n\nfourth one:\n=======\n11\n12\n13""")

# list of blocks to be read
names = ["next one:", "fourth one:"]

# file processing
with open("f.txt") as r, open("r.txt", "w") as w:
    capture = False
    startingline = False
    for line in r:
        l = line.strip()  # remove \n for l
        if not l:
            continue      # skip empty lines
        if l in names:    # check if this is a block we watch out for
            startingline = True      # this will "eat" the ===== line that follows
            capture = True           # this allows capturing 
            continue
        if startingline:  # "eat" ========
            if set(l) == set("="):
                startingline = False
            continue
        
        if capture:       # if we capture we keep all isdigit lines and stop
            if l.isdigit():
                w.write(line)
            elif set(l) == set("="):   # if we encounter another ==== line
                capture = False

with open("r.txt") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Output:

```
4   # next one
5
6
7
11  # fourth one
12
13
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this

```
# put your text in here
with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.read().split()

# all your numbers will save here
with open("output.txt", "a") as f:
    [f.write(i + "\n") for i in text if i.isnumeric()]
```

Comment: many thanks for your replay but  i want to check the name of the Block if its match and then take the content of it.

Comment: oh sorry, thought you wanted all the numbers

Answer (score 0):

As I recognize problem is to leave only numbers in data readed from file. You can read text file into `df` dataframe with column named for example `line` and then remove non numbers:

```
pd.to_numeric(df.line, errors = 'coerce').dropna()
```

Then save the `df` to file.

Comment: This does not eliminate the numbers from the blocks that are NOT wanted.

Comment: thanks for your replay. it is about the content of specific block until the next or the next  block